# Where is the/a hospital/post office/hotel/park?

Tags: articles

I am new to this town.

> Where is the hospital/post office/hotel/park?

> Where is a hospital/post office/hotel/park?

> Where can I find the hospital/post office/hotel/park?

> Where can I find a hospital/post office/hotel/park?

Can you compare "the" and "a" before these nouns? Which are correct? If all of them are correct, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is the hospital/post office/hotel/park?

> Where is a hospital/post office/hotel/park?

> Where can I find the hospital/post office/hotel/park?

> Where can I find a hospital/post office/hotel/park?

The 2nd example is unusual.

Of the rest, if you are aware that there is only one of the facilities you have listed, or if you have identified your preferred one in the earlier part of your conversation,
you may use the 1st or the 3rd example.

If there are several of these facilities, and you do not mind any of them, you may use the 4th example.  However, if you have a preference, you can say

> Where can I find [**the nearest**] hospital/post office/hotel/park?